# Add Azure Availability Set to Load Balancer (backend pool) to with Terraform

Tags: azure, terraform, azure-rm

Hope someone can help me. I created a cluster of multiple VMs inside an Availability Set and a Load Balancer.

With Terraform I can say to add the single NICs to the BackendPool:

```
resource "azurerm_network_interface_backend_address_pool_association" "backendPool" {
  count                   = "${var.nb_instances}"
  network_interface_id    = "${element(azurerm_network_interface.nic.*.id, count.index + 1)}"
  ip_configuration_name   = "ipconfig01"
  backend_address_pool_id = "${var.backendPoolID}"
}
```

Instead of adding each VM separate, I want to say the LB to add the whole AV-Set, which works fine with the Azure GUI, but I can not find any solution to do it inside Terraform.

I tried to add this resource to my AV-Set module and replaced the "network_interface_id" with the AV-Set ID, but it didn´t work.

Is there such a solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you say you can add the availability set to the load balancer in Azure GUI, actually, Azure also associate the Nics of the VMs in the availability set to the load balancer backend pool. It's the same as it provides in Terraform. The difference is that Azure GUI does all the things behind for you. But you do all the things yourself in Terraform. So there are no other solutions to add the VMs to the load balancer backend pool in Terraform.